# Difference between "sima" and "cueva"?

Tags: español-neutral, selección-de-palabras

What are the difference between the words "*sima*" and "*cueva*"?

It's just a formal way to say it? Are they synonymous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Cueva* has a wider meaning; a *cueva* is a *sima* only when it is vertically deep. You can fall into a *sima*. If you want, a *sima* is a combination of cave and abyss.